# link_to_if in Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

a question regarding link_to_if in rails 4.0 because I just upgraded. There was no problem with older Rails 3 Version.

Simplified example:

```
link_to_if(user, "User", user.id)
  content_tag(:span, "No User")
end
```

So for a given user object it just set its id into the link. My problem now is in case of no user (nil)/can even hardcode "false" here. In old Rails 3 it just ignores the options.

In Rails 4 it strangely triggers the options even the condition is not fulfilled. Why is it? Do I really need to check for nil even the condition already did?

Edit, real code:

```
def link_to_previous_poster
  link_to_if(@poster.prev, "< Previous".html_safe, poster_path(@poster.prev, :skip => skip_poster.to_i-1), :accesskey => 'h') do |name|
    content_tag(:span, '< Previous'.html_safe, :class => "current")
  end
end
```

In case of @poster.prev==nil it triggers poster_path with the nil value which leads to a routing error.

The Error on browser is:

ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Posters#show
Showing /.../show.html.haml where line #5 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posters", :id=>nil, :format=>nil, :skip=>-1} missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: Have you tried `link_to_if(user.present?, "User", user.id) [etc.]`?

Comment: it doesn't work, even I use `link_to_if(false, "User", user.id)` it calls user.id

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Does it show a link? Does it throw an exception?

Comment: It shows an exception. In my real case a routing exception because it routes id=nil as required parameter. But like said it shouldn't triggered at all, the condition isn't met.

Comment: Refusing to provide the real code causing the issue or the real exception you're receiving (stack trace, etc.) makes it difficult for us to give you real help.

Comment: I added the real code in the question.

Comment: The exact error, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
poster_path(@poster.prev, :skip => skip_poster.to_i-1)
```

This code is going to execute regardless of `@poster.prev` being nil/falsy. You're passing the above into `link_to_if` as an argument; it's going to be evaluated and it's **return value** will be passed into the `link_to_if` as an argument.

I would rewrite the helper

```
def link_to_previous_poster
  return content_tag(:span, '< Previous'.html_safe, :class => "current") if @poster.prev.blank?

  link_to(@poster.prev, "< Previous".html_safe, poster_path(@poster.prev, :skip => skip_poster.to_i-1), :accesskey => 'h')
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I already rewrote the code, I just wondered why the option part is being evaluated when condition wasn't met.